# Check status code with ExUnit failed, but actual REST test success

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ex-unit

I'm writing a controller function where it will check for a condition ( keyword to be valid ) before either to render a json object or error object if failed.

**router.ex**

```
scope "/api", DongNghiaWeb do
    pipe_through :api
    scope "/tim_kiem" do
      get "/tu/:word"   , APIWordController, :search_word
[...]
```

**word_controller.ex**

```
def search_word(conn, %{"word" => word}) do
  conn
  |> check_invalid_keyword(word)
  |> render("search.json", words: word |> String.trim |> Words.suggest)
end

defp check_invalid_keyword(conn, keyword) do
  unless Words.keyword_valid?(String.trim(keyword)) do
    conn
    |> put_status(400)
    |> json(%{
      error: "Invalid keyword"
    })
  end
  conn
end
```

**word_controller_test.ex**

```
test "response error when word is not valid", %{conn: conn} do
  response = get(conn,api_word_path(conn, :search_word, "a3d"))
    |> json_response(400)
  assert response["error"] == "Invalid keyword"
end
```

When running `mix test`, the results will be like so :

```
** (RuntimeError) expected response with status 400, got: 200, with body: {"data":[]}
```

But when I try testing with a REST client ( Insomnia, for example ), the json will return to be `{ error : "Invalid keyword" }` just fine.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Elixir does not have mutable variables. In your `check_invalid_keyword` function, you are just returning the original `conn` regardless of what happens. You should probably use an if expression and use an else clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is writing the response to the connection twice when `Words.keyword_valid?(String.trim(keyword))` is falsy.

The first write happens when you call `|> json(...)` and the second one when you call `render`. Your code does not prevent `render` being called when `json` has already been called. The browser connection ends after the first write, so you see the right output with Insomnia but the testing setup uses the last response written to the connection.

Fixing this requires a bit of restructuring of your code. Here's how I would do it:

```
def search_word(conn, %{"word" => word}) do
  if Words.keyword_valid?(String.trim(word)) do
    conn
    |> render("search.json", words: word |> String.trim() |> Words.suggest())
  else
    conn
    |> put_status(400)
    |> json(%{
      error: "Invalid keyword"
    })
  end
end
```

---

Edit: here's one way to do what you requested in the comment below:

```
def search_word(conn, %{"word" => word}) do
  with {:ok, conn} <- check_invalid_keyword(conn, word) do
    conn
    |> render("search.json", words: word |> String.trim() |> Words.suggest())
  end
end

def check_invalid_keyword(conn, keyword) do
  if Words.keyword_valid?(String.trim(keyword)) do
    {:ok, conn}
  else
    conn
    |> put_status(400)
    |> json(%{
      error: "Invalid keyword"
    })
  end
end
```

When the keyword is invalid, the return value fails to match the `with` clause and is returned as is. If it was valid, the `do` block gets executed.

Comment: Thanks ! But because I'm repeating the `check_invalid_keyword` for multiple function in the controller, which is why I wrote it as a separate function. How would I achieve it here ? While your code answered my question, it doesn't really resolve my problem

Comment: By "repeating", you mean like `conn |> check_invalid_keyword(word) |> check_invalid_keyword(word2) |> check_invalid_keyword(word3) |> render(...)`?

Comment: No I mean in function `show(conn, etc. )` and `search(conn, etc. )` will both need to use the check

Comment: Ah. I've added a solution for that. Let me know if it works!